# When to use Proverbial?

Tags: word-usage

I was just curious when I could use the word Proverbial in a sentence. Would it be correct to use when referring to often cliched expressions (i.e. putting the "proverbial" pedal to the metal, giving them the "proverbial" green light...) or is it solely used for idioms?

Thanks!

Comment: It's the "proverbial" ***pedal***, not ***petal***. A somewhat loose usage of ***proverbial** = [as referred to by a "proverb"]*. It's okay to use it in respect of modern sayings/idioms even though they're not really "proverbs", but it wouldn't make any sense at all to call something *proverbial* unless it was well known/cliched.

Comment: In my mind, *the proverbial* is an idiomatic expression in that context, roughly meaning: *the idiomatic*, or occasionally, *the oft mentioned*. There is no proverb about the *pedal to the metal*, which is part of the idiomatic phrase, *put the pedal to the metal*.

Comment: There's an interesting recent thread on this in the American Dialect Society email list http://www.americandialect.org/publications/ads-l-the-american-dialect-society-email-discussion-list , occasioned by a sports announcer speaking of a boxer "going in for the proverbial kill". (Sorry, the link doesn't go to that thread, just to the main ADS-L page.)

Comment: Is that correct though? Going for the "proverbial" kill? I can also think of "finding the needle in the proverbial haystack"... I have the feeling that I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notwithstanding the definitions mentioned by FunbleFingers and others above, in my experience "proverbial" is commonly used in a much looser sense which does include sayings or catchphrases such as "pedal to the metal" that are not the subject of actual proverbs! It's not to be taken literally.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I think this dictionary definition clarifies usage:

> **pro·ver·bi·al**
>
> adjective
> \prəˈvərbēəl, -və̄b-, -vəib-\
>
> 1 :  **of, relating to, or resembling a proverb**
>
> *the proverbial style*
>
> *proverbial wisdom*
>
> *proverbial comparisons*
>
> 2 :  that has become a
> proverb or byword :  **commonly spoken of**
>
> *the proverbial restlessness
> of sailors — Herman Melville*
>
> **Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary**